# Klein-Gordon mode functions in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm currently tackling QFT in curved spacetimes for the first time, mainly using "Quantum fields in curved space" by Birrell and Preskill's notes on QFT in curved spaces, to get a general idea of the subject.

We know that, in a globally hyperbolic spacetime, the Cauchy problem for the Klein-Gordon field is well-posed, in the sense that, given a pair of smooth, compactly supported initial conditions on a spacelike Cauchy surface, there exists a unique solution, defined on all the spacetime, that matches these conditions. Let $S$ be the set of this type of solutions.

We want to find the general solution, then quantize it and impose the equal time canonical commutation relations.

It is said, in both references, that we can always expand the field as

$$\phi=\sum_{i} a_{i}u_{i}+a_{i}^{\star}u_{i}^{\star}$$

where $\{u_{i}\}$ is a complete set of solutions of the covariant Klein-Gordon equation, satisfying the following orthonormality condition:

$$(u_{i},u_{j})=\delta_{ij}$$
$$(u_{i}^{\star},u_{j}^{\star})=-\delta_{ij}$$
$$(u_{i},u_{j}^{\star})=0$$

It follows that

$$a_{i}=(u_{i},\phi)$$
$$a_{i}^{\star}=-(u_{i}^{\star},\phi)$$

It is said that these scalar products can be evaluated in any spacelike Cauchy surface, because the Klein-Gordon inner product is slice independent. Now, to prove the slice independent property, as far as I know, we must use the fact that the functions in input are compactly supported in a Cauchy surface (at least, they must go to zero at spatial infinity).

However, in some cases, we use mode functions that do not belong to $S$. For example, in the simplest case of Minkowski spacetime, we use plane waves, that are outside $S$ but complete. And it is true even in other geometries, such as a spatially flat 2d FRW spacetime (see Birrell, ch.3). For such mode functions, the fact that the scalar products listed above (the orthonormality conditions, for example) are slice independent is not trivial and we have to prove it, in order to say that these relations are well-defined, right?